# Does NASA really report the power of rockets in horsepower?

Tags: rockets, nasa, power, launch-vehicle

On a recent episode of The Late Show with Stephen Colbert, Dr. Neil deGrasse Tyson said:

> And to this day NASA will still report the power of rockets in horsepower, which is completely absurd, because no matter how many horses you string together, they will not elevate into space.So it just doesn’t make any sense!

**Question:** Is it true? Does NASA still report the power of rockets in horsepower?

Is this in press briefings, or educational material, or scientific literature?

cued at `04:35`:

Comment: Why not, it's a unit of power people are familiar with. They use other absurd units such as inches and lbf

Comment: @JCRM I suppose because power is not a useful unit for launch vehicles. The question here is about does or doesn't, not should or shouldn't.

Comment: It (or power/weight) is useful to get a feeling of just how much energy is being processed by such a small device.

Comment: follow-up: [How did NASA calculate 22 million “rocket horsepower” for the SLS Booster?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41850/12102)

Comment: Maybe this question can be rephrased to "does NDGT use humor as a rhetorical device?".

Comment: Whatever it is NDGT is using, it's not humor.

Comment: @RussellBorogove do you mean a) he's being serious, or b) he tried to make a joke but it's so lame it doesn't qualify as humor (or c) none of the above)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, part of NASA's function is public communication. As such they will use units such as "[Aircraft Carriers](https://blogs.nasa.gov/Rocketology/tag/sls/page/4/)" "[School Buses](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/588413main_SLS_Fun_Facts.pdf)" and "[horsepower](https://www.nasa.gov/sls/booster-aimed-and-ready-to-fire.html)"

While not precise, expressing thrust in terms of horsepower notionally allows people to understand it more.

> "What's impressive about this test is when ignited, the booster will be operating at about 3.6 million pounds of thrust, or 22 million horsepower," said Alex Priskos, manager of the SLS Boosters Office at Marshall. "This test firing is critical to enable validation of our design."

Comment: Yes, for PR purposes only.

Comment: I've just asked [How does NASA calculate "rocket horsepower"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41850/12102)

Comment: In Stack Exchange, link-only answers are discouraged. If the link breaks, the answer becomes useless.

Comment: The content of the links is unimportant (all three mention horsepower) They're merely recent examples. If they do disappear, that may mean the answer has changed.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary for each reader to go off-site three times to get the answer to the question. Link-only answers are always discouraged in SE and actively discouraged here in Space SE. It's a long-standing policy.

Comment: The answer isn't in the links. The text you lincluded didn't answer your question.

but as you wish @uhoh

Comment: I think "public outreach" better represents what I meant to write @OrganicMarble, do you think that clarifies it enough, or should I go further?

Comment: I agree that it was just for public "relate-ability".

Comment: `-1` Accepting because correct but maintaining down vote for now because of link-onliness and [whatever this turns out to be](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/527199/217285) ;-)

Comment: Again, this isn't a link-only answer. It stands complete without the links. If a person is not going to trust that the links contain examples of NASA using horespower when talking about rocket engine output then one isn't going to trust that the text quoted from the link isn't made up. If I had found an explanation of why NASA uses it, and refused to quote i, you would have a point - but I have not. Such a quote would greatly improve this answer

Comment: There's a video of an airline pilot who's quite into technical things related to cars and planes, in which he calculates how many horsepowers a F-14 Tomcat has -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC-7wRmMH2g  While computing horsepower for a jet plane is fun and bogus, it allows an average human to grasp to difference jet power makes when compared to propeller driven planes. So, horsepowers of a rocket may be bonkers, but it's a concept everyday people are familiar with. How powerful is the Saturn V? Very. How much? Very much. Horsepower may be a good crutch to convey the meaning of "Very much"

Answer (score 1):

Using the inappropriate unit horsepower for rocket engines has a very long tradition. When the V2 A4 rocket of WWII was presented to ignorant NSDAP government officials by the Wernher von Braun team, the only useful comparative value was horsepower known from automotive engines. A thrust value using forth units was not understood.

One offical had the very stupid idea of using rocket engines for railway locomotives.

Comment: It does make one wonder about "government officials". Some things never change, irrespective of time or the politics of "government officials". Some "government officials" around the world think Covid-19 is fake, others that coal still has a future as an energy source, not to mention other misconceived ideas. If horse power is all their little uneducated or inexperienced minds can understand, talk to them about horse power. They hold the purse strings & "someone" needs finance.

Comment: [Sandia Nation labs rocket rail test system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvqDj3me37o)

Comment: This is a great anecdote. Do you have a source? A quick Google didn't find anything.

Comment: I remember reading about that in a book some decades ago. I have to search about 5 books in my book shelf.